# ORACLE SQL - Get limited rows with maximum values in a column with rownum but without a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle DB which consists of products and stock. I want to get a limited number of products in output (say 10 products) with maximum stock. There are also other conditions that I would check which involves inner join with multiple tables.

This query randomly selects 10 products from the table then sorts it, so its not helpful:

```
Select prod_code, stock from producttable where rownum < 10
--and lots of other conditions
order by stock desc
```

I searched and found this below method. But this runs forever because the inner query is a full table output:
    Select * from (Select prod_code, stock from producttable where
    -- lots of other conditions
    order by stock desc) where rownum < 10

Can someone please help me find a way to do this accurately and efficiently ?

Following is the query used -

```
SELECT * from (SELECT  
wbob.p1  
FROM t1 wbob  
Inner join t2 wboc on wboc.p2 = wbob.p2  
Inner join t3 wboa on wboa.p2 = wbob.p2  
Inner join t4 mfa on mfa.p3 = wbob.p4  
Left outer join t5 mfb on mfb.p3 = wbob.p4  
Inner join t6 mfc on mfc.p3 = wbob.p4  
Inner join t7 mfd on mfd.p3 = wbob.p4  
Inner join t8 mfg on mfg.p3 = wbob.p4  
Inner join t9 sta on sta.p5 = wbob.p4  
Inner join t10 stb on stb.p6 = sta.p6  
Inner join t11 stc on stc.p7 = stb.p7  
WHERE  
wboa.stock > '0'  
and wboa.p8 in ('14','198')  
and wboc.p9  = '187'  
and mfd.p10 > 0  
and stb.p11 > 0  
and trim(mfa.p12) = 'ACT'  
and mfa.p13 = 'N'  
and trim(stc.p7) = '3333'  
and mfc.p14 = 11  
and mfc.p15 = 3333  
and mfg.p16 = 1  
and mfc.p17 = 'Y'  
and mfd.p18 = 'N'  
and mfa.p19 = 'W'  
and wbob.p1 NOT IN (Select wbob1.p1  
from t1 wbob1  
inner join t3 wboa1 ON wboa1.p2 = wbob1.p2  
where wboa1.stock > '0'  
and wboa1.p8 NOT IN ('14','198'))  
and (wbob.p4 NOT IN (Select mfb7.p3 from t5 mfb7) OR wbob.p4 IN (Select mfb8.p3 from t5 mfb8  
where mfb8.p20 = 0))  
ORDER BY stb.p11 DESC) where rownum < 10
```

[Explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pglp5.png)

Comment: `rownum < 10` does not randomize the results! Using rownum to limit the out results is the most horrible way to do it. If you're on 12c there's the `FIRST 10 rows only` clause. There are tons of other methids. Also, the requirement is not really clear, sorry ... the last sentence does not sum up the lines before it. Can you explain it more explicitly please?

Comment: @g00dy, thank you for responding. I tried using 'FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY' . It says 'SQL command not properly ended'. Requirement is to get the products satisfying all the conditions and with maximum stock. So the query has inner joins with 7 other tables, lots of subqueries and 'where' conditions. If I use rownum directly, it selects the first 10 products matching the conditions and then sorting it based on stock value. If I use a subquery to sort the products and then use rownum, the query runs forever. I have checked the explain plan and it uses only the indexes, no full table scans.

Comment: the clause is `fetch first 10 rows only`, that's the whole syntax. The problem with rownum is that it first limits the query to 10 rows and *then* it sorts the result. A proper use of it can be seen in the comment below by Gordon Linoff. So in brief - your query runs for a long time if you don't limit the rows, that could be correct, because you might select thousands of lines. Even if you use indexes, this might get slow. Check the number of rows returned by the query with count (no limitation) to check that. If that's the case, then you might want to consider partitions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 12c without a subquery using `fetch first n rows only`

```
Select prod_code, stock 
from producttable
where ... 
--and lots of other conditions
order by stock desc
fetch first 10 rows only
```

However, this will not solve the problem you are complaining about which is the performance of the query and how the inner query is a full table output.  This is actually necessary and this solution will do the same.  In order to sort stock to get the top stock items, the db will have to look at and sort all the possible rows.  How else can you get the top items without looking at all of them?  There might be ways to improve this, like an index on the stock value, but I wouldn't recommend that without knowing detail your data model.

Comment: well said @unleashed

Comment: @Unleashed, thanks for responding. However 'FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY' didnt work. It gave me syntax error. If I update the table and sort to have products with higher stock in the top, Would that work ? If yes, how could I do that ?

Comment: As I mentioned, `fetch first 10 rows only` is only available on 12c (12.1 and up).  If you are on 11g and below, you'll have to select and order in the subquery, then grab the top rows from the outer query as in Gordon's answer.  Google for Oracle and 'top n' queries for more information.

Comment: Hi @unleashed, Yes, My DB is on 11g. I'm aware of the subquery method, but it literally runs forever coz the subquery has numerous inner joins and 'where' conditions (which are very important for me to get the right output). Is there no other way of doing this ? I regret using oracle DB now, it happens quite easily in SQL server (Select top 100).

Comment: Well, if you provide your full query, and explain plan for your query, more information about your tables/data model, and some test data, this community could help you out.  You've got the answer to your question about running a top-n query on Oracle, but doing a top-n query alone is not a problem.  I'm sure it is a problem in your query alone.

Comment: I have added the full query and the explain plan in my question.

Comment: To be clear, your problem is going to be in your inner query with the order by.  Looking at the query, there is nothing I can help with as long as you don't provide an explain plan and more detail on your data model.  The query alone does not provide enough information.

Comment: @Unleashed, there's a link for the explain plan right below the query. Please let me know specifically what else you may need. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, I can see the most of the cost is in the three hash joins, probably each on a full index scan, which doesn't seem to be to bad.  I'll re-echo some of the sentiment in other answers and comments.  You want to get the 10 products with the most stock.  In order to do this, you have to look at all the stock and sort it to get the 10 most.  There is no way around it,  Another option is to create a materialized view with the stock count, keep it refreshed, so you can get the top 10 easier.

Comment: Thank you @unleashed. Could you please explain more or provide some reference which I can use to create materialised views and get top 10 products with highest stocks ?

Comment: Oracle docs and google searches for materialized view will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery:

```
select p.*
from (Select prod_code, stock
      from producttable
      order by stock desc
     ) p
where rownum < 10;
```

For performance, you want an index on `producttable(stock, prod_code)`.  The subquery isn't causing the performance issue; the lack of index is.